# How to disable keyboard on Cordova IOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Currently Im creating a cordova xcode app. Im just editing the default index.html. Im not configuring xib ar adding any element to it. Just pure html, css, and javascript. I have input text on my html and it is read by xcode and automatically pops up the keyboard once the input text is clicked which I dont want to happen. Should anyone of you know how to disable it pro-grammatically? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If there is no keyboard, how would the user type anything? And it's a feature of the `UIWebView`, so it's not possible to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to achieve it:
1) Make your textfield as readonly
2) Make use of this plugin and hide the keybaord manually
https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/785

Answer (score 0):

Already a "done" button is there,just click on it.